# pandas how can modify rows using str.match goups

Tags: python, pandas, string, regex-group

I'm a newbie in pandas and I need your help.
I have this df and I would like to modify the content of 'Dig' column in this way:

Dig Dest

10&&-7 INTCH1

260&&-4 INTCH2

basically what I would like to do is split the string 10&&-7 into two parts (10 and 7) and starting from the first element, remove the last character (for example remove 0 from 10) and add '1' until reaching the value 7.

So the first row should become:

10 INTCH1

11 INTCH1

12 INTCH1

13 INTCH1

14 INTCH1

15 INTCH1

16 INTCH1

17 INTCH1

I done it using python, these is an extract from my code just as an example:

```
        elif re_dig3.match(cur_line):                                       
        matched = re_dig3.match(cur_line)
        int1 = matched.group(1)
        int2 = matched.group(2)
        int11, int22 = int(int1[-1]), int(int2[-1])
        while int11 <= int22:
            file_writing(new_file, (int1[:-1]+str(int11)) + '\n')
            int11 += 1
        dict_list['list_dig3'].append(cur_line)
```

where I defined 2 groups (int1 and int2), took the last character, changed type in int and create a while loop where I wrote into a file the result desired.

I would like to obtain this result usign pandas because I think it's faster than python loop.

I obtained, from the previous df, a new one with two columns with two regex groups ('0' and '1':

```
df2intreg['Dig'].str.extract(r'(\d+)&&-(\d+)$')
```

0   1

10  7

But now I don't know to proceed, any hint it's very appreciated.

thanks,
Davide

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to parse `Dig`, create a list of integers defined by 'Dig', stick them into a list for each row, and then `explode`

First, load the sample data

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""
Dig Dest
10&&-7 INTCH1
260&&-4 INTCH2
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Next, parse `'Dig'` by using `str.split()` and split them into separate columns

```
df[['start','num']] = df['Dig'].str.split('&&-').values.tolist()
df[['start','num']] = df[['start','num']].astype(int)
```

We get

```
    Dig     Dest    start   num
0   10&&-7  INTCH1  10      7
1   260&&-4 INTCH2  260     4
```

Now we create a list of integers per row

```
import numpy as np
df['elements'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['start'] + np.arange(row['num']+1), axis=1)
```

to get the lists in `'elements'` column:

```
    Dig     Dest    start   num elements
0   10&&-7  INTCH1  10      7   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
1   260&&-4 INTCH2  260     4   [260, 261, 262, 263, 264]
```

Finally, explode and select the columns we care about

```
df.explode('elements')[['elements','Dest']]
```

to obtain

```
   elements Dest
0   10  INTCH1
0   11  INTCH1
0   12  INTCH1
0   13  INTCH1
0   14  INTCH1
0   15  INTCH1
0   16  INTCH1
0   17  INTCH1
1   260 INTCH2
1   261 INTCH2
1   262 INTCH2
1   263 INTCH2
1   264 INTCH2
```

### Edit: Using RegEx instead of split

If the values in the `'Dig'` do not have as consistent a format as in the question, then one can use regex for the first step, like so. First, load the data

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""
Dig Dest
10&&-7 INTCH1
260&&-4 INTCH2
211&&-3&-6&-8 INTCH3
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
```

then extract the first two numbers from each element in `'Dig'`:

```
df[['start','num']] = df['Dig'].str.findall('\d+').apply(lambda l: l[:2]).values.tolist()
df
```

we get

```
    Dig             Dest    start   num
0   10&&-7          INTCH1  10      7
1   260&&-4         INTCH2  260     4
2   211&&-3&-6&-8   INTCH3  211     3
```

Then proceed as before

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try ;-)

Comment: @Davide_Pex does my example work for you (with the df from my answer)

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestions but encountered two problems:
1) df1[['start','num']] = df1['Dig'].str.split('&&-').values.tolist()
KeyError: "None of [Index(['start', 'num'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
2) Using str.split('&&-') I caught also this format (just as example) :211&&-3&-6&-8
For this format I used, in my python code, this regex:
 (r'^(\d+)&&-(\d)&-(\d)&-(\d)$')
I have more or less 20 different formats of number and I thought using regex instead of split is more flexible and accurate, but  I don't know how to handle regex groups in pandas

Comment: Yes, with the df in your explanation it works well. Thanks